# Getting all entries less than max price and more than one entry from having

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the Northwind database from W3 schools and my query is

```
SELECT Price from products group by Price having Price < max(Price)
```

It's currently showing no results, but how would I fix that? You can see the database here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_having

Additionally, is it possible to get more than one entry returned from having, i.e, all rows that meet the having clause condition. For example, in the link above, only unique countries are returned that meet the condition.

EDIT: Also with the Northwind database:

```
SELECT *FROM Customers GROUP BY City HAVING COUNT(City) > 2;
```

Why does it have unexpected behaviour, i.e, not return the rows where there are more than two occurrences of the city.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The first question is about fixing my query so that I can get all the rows that are less than max(price). The second question is getting a table of all rows that meet the having condition, because in the example in the link, only unique countries are returned.

Comment: I'm trying to get the rows where the price is less than the max though. That would get me the max price

Comment: @Akina sorry it's late

Comment: It seems like you should do the same kind of implementation that @Zaynul did for your Customers query

Comment: @SebastianPeterlin for the edit? If so how would I compare cities to a count?

Comment: @user2793618 pls do not ask further questions in your post once the original has been answered! If you have a new question, ask it properly in its own post!

Comment: They're all related though as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add the max(price) to the select

```
DROP table if exists t;

create table t
(price int);
insert into t values (1),(2),(1),(2),(3),(10);

SELECT Price, max(price) mp from t group by Price;
```

you get

```
+-------+------+
| Price | mp   |
+-------+------+
|     1 |    1 |
|     2 |    2 |
|     3 |    3 |
|    10 |   10 |
+-------+------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

the having test is on the grouped items and is never true . To produce the correct result you need the sub query suggested by @akina.

Comment: Why would the having clause never be true?

Comment: I’m confused as to why having on grouped items would be false

Comment: It can never be less than itself as shown by the sample output in my answer.

Comment: Oh wait so it compares it to each group? So then how does data “flow” in sql?

Comment: What is it that I’m actually manipulating in each clause?

Comment: Ahh Question creep...search for mysql order of operations.

Comment: sorry I’m just super new to sql

Answer (score 2):

try like below

```
SELECT Price from products 
where  Price < (select max(Price) from products)
```

Comment: Why does there need to be a new subquery?

Comment: And how would I do it with having?

Comment: @user2793618 `price` and `max(price)` are the datas from differemt grouping level - they cannot be mixed. So subquery is used for to convert aggreagted value to scalar.

Comment: @Akina do you also know why the unexpected behaviour is happening in my edit?

Comment: @user2793618 The reason of the problem in your code is absolutely the same - mixing scalar and aggregated value in one expression.

Comment: @Akina how would I fix this?

Comment: @user2793618 Subquery is the simplest solution. You may use CTE (if DBMS allows) and either convert this subquery to CTE or apply `RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Price DESC)` and select prices which' rank is over 1. PS. If this answer solves your task then mark it as accepted.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I'm pretty confused as to why group by also only returns one row too.